# Are these formulas for the critical value for detection interchangeable?

Tags: spectroscopy, radioactivity

I am trying to compare equations for calculating the critical value for detection. One is presented by the ISO standards (https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S0969804316306455?via%3Dihub)
where $y^* = k \cdot \sqrt{a\cdot (a+1) \cdot (n_a + n_b) } =k\cdot \sqrt{2n_0} = k\cdot u(0)$

- $n_a$, $n_b$ are counts in the right and left side regions of the peak
- $k$ is the quantile of the standardized normal distribution
- $a=\frac{b}{2l}$ where $b$ is the number of channel defining the region of interest for a spectrum - peak and $l$ is the number of channel at the right and left side of the peak used

It is presented, that $a\cdot (a+1) \cdot (n_a + n_b) =2n_0$, where $n_0$ sands for counts of blank

and other equation used at my workplace (by Obrusník and Kučera, The digital methods of peak area computation and detection limit in gamma-ray spectrometry. Radiochem Radioanal Letters. 1978, 32(3-4), 149-160): $L_D = \frac{k}{2}\sqrt{(GA-NA) \cdot 2 \cdot (N - 2) } $, where

- $GA$ gross area
- $NA$ net area
- $N$ is the number of channels in the section of interest

It seems to me that: $GA -NA = B = n_0$

$a\cdot (a+1) = \frac{b}{2l}\cdot (\frac{b}{2l}+1) = \frac{b}{2l}\cdot(\frac{b+2l}{2l}) = \frac{b}{4l^2}\cdot N$

$\frac{b}{2l} \cdot N \cdot \frac{n_a+n_b}{2l}$, where $\frac{n_a+n_b}{2l}$ is average number of counts for one channel belonging to background.. and therefore $N\cdot \frac{n_a+n_b}{2l} = B =(?) n_0  $

but I didn't even arrive to $k \cdot \sqrt{a\cdot (a+1) \cdot (n_a + n_b) } =k\cdot \sqrt{2n_0}.$

Is there anything I overlooked/didn't understand right?

Thank you